# jQuery - Building object arrays with html5 data attribute selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using HTML 5 data attributes to key rows of data in a table. I need to iterate the rows and gather the data into an object collection.   I created a class to represent my row data:

```
function SomeItem(description, finalPrice, percentDiscount) {
    this.Description = description;
    this.FinalPrice = finalPrice;
    this.PercentDiscount = percentDiscount;
}
```

An event fires which triggers the collection of this data.

```
$.each($('.ItemPriceBox'), function () {
            var uniqueid = $(this).data('uniqueid');
            var finalPrice = $(this).val();
        });
```

The final piece of data, percentDiscount should be retrieved using the `data-uniqueid` attribute.  I'm not sure how to do this.

I want...

```
SomeItem[] items;
$.each($('.ItemPriceBox'), function () {
            var uniqueid = $(this).data('uniqueid');
            var finalPrice = $(this).val();
            var percentDiscount = $('.ItemDiscountBox').where("uniqueid = " + uniqueid);
            items[i] = new SomeItem(uniqueid,finalPrice,percentDiscount);
        });
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be like this

```
var percentDiscount = $(".ItemDiscountBox[uniqueid='"+uniqueid +"']");
```

Comment: +1 Thats pretty close.  I just finished up with a slightly different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your pseudo-code `where`, use filter:

```
var percentDiscount = $('.ItemDiscountBox').filter("[uniqueid='" + uniqueid + "']");

$('.ItemPriceBox').each( function (i) {
    var uniqueid = $(this).data('uniqueid');
    var finalPrice = $(this).val();
    var percentDiscount = $('.ItemDiscountBox').filter("[uniqueid='" + uniqueid + "']");
    items[i] = new SomeItem(uniqueid,finalPrice,percentDiscount);
});
```

You can also use `.each()` instead of `jQuery.each()`

Comment: This is the right idea, but 3nigma's solution is more concise.